# Mime type for liquid templates (to use in paperclip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, content-type

I want to be able to validate that the content type of my attachment is a liquid template, but I don't know what should I write.

The examples show this:

```
 :content_type => { :content_type => "image/jpeg" }
```

What would be the content type for a liquid file?

Comment: If you are on a *nix-based OS (for example, Mac OS or Linux), you can do `file --mime-type -b FILE_PATH_HERE` from the command line. I wouldn't use a content type as the only way to know that the file is what the uploader says it is though.

Comment: @Skram, I have done that, and for some liquid files (the one that start with <html>) I get 'text/html', and for the others that don't start with <html> I get 'text/plain'. So, I guess a .liquid file can have several mime types?